# A problem of understanding the code in the corejava book (11ed) section 6.4

Tags: java, encryption

In the section 6.4 of corejava, author introduces a code example about Caesar cipher,what the code `new byte[] { (byte) -key[0] }`   mean in the decrypt method???

```
package serviceLoader;
public interface Cipher
{
byte[] encrypt(byte[] source, byte[] key);
byte[] decrypt(byte[] source, byte[] key);
int strength();
}

package serviceLoader.impl;
public class CaesarCipher implements Cipher
{
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] source, byte[] key)
{
var result = new byte[source.length];
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
result[i] = (byte)(source[i] + key[0]);
return result;
}
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] source, byte[] key)
{
return encrypt(source, new byte[] { (byte) -key[0] });
}
public int strength() { return 1; }
}
```

Comment: A caesar cipher is when you change the letters according to a key. The key specifices how many characters you have to shift. When you decode your cipher you need to move back exactly as many characters as you shifted it when encrypting. When the encrypt key is 5 the decrypt key has to be -5. I would recomend changing the key type to an integer as you only ever need the first entry in the given array anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`new byte[] { (byte) -key[0] }` means a new byte array containing a byte-casted 1st element (`[0]`) of "key" array, whose sign is being inverted (eg by the `-` )